# partially inject components in typescript (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, typescript

currently I use `$inject` to inject components in my controller:

```
export class MyClass{

    public static $inject = [
        "$depedencyA",
        "$depedencyB",
        "$depedencyC"   
    ];

    constructor(
            private $depedencyA: IDependencyA,
            private $depedencyB: IDependencyB,
            private $depedencyC: IDependencyC         
        )
        {

        }

}
```

This works fine when creating an instance of `MyClass` like `let myClassInstance=new MyClass();`

But what if I want to pass a depedency that cannot be directly injected by the class itself?

`let myClassInstance=new MyClass(anotherDependency);`

Well of course I have to extend `MyClass` to accept this parameter in the constructor

```
constructor(
            private $depedencyA: IDependencyA,
            private $depedencyB: IDependencyB,
            private $depedencyC: IDependencyC,
            private $anotherDependency: any
        )
        {

        }
```

..but then the injection cannot work anymore because the parameters array does not match the actual constructur signature anymore.
How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work: `let myClassInstance=new MyClass();` because you're not letting angular wire up the dependencies for you. You're now responsible for providing all of the dependencies for this class which you haven't in your example.

If you're newing these objects up yourself, then nothing changes when you add another dependency - you will have to provide this manually as well.

You can't really do partial injection with angularjs' DI. You will need to either new that object up yourself and provide all the dependencies, or you will have to register the new dependency as a service of some kind.